# Number to counter

Tags: php

I have a number, let's say it's 5 for now. The thing I want is to get an array from 0 to 5.

So as an example:

```
$input = 5;
// Do something
$output = array(0,1,2,3,4,5);
```

I did something like this:

```
$i = 0;
$input = 5;
$output = array();
while($i <= $input) {
    $output[] = $i;
    $i++;
}
```

A quick `print_r($output);` will result in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
)
```

Looks good, but I was hoping for a smaller and quicker solution. Any suggestions? Is their a PHP function I'm missing/don't know of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe [`range()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)?

```
$output = range(0, $input);
print_r($output);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
    [5] => 5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = 5;
$output = array();
for($i = 0; $i <= $input; $i++) {
    $output[] = $i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = 5;
$output = array();
for($i=0; $i<=$input; $i++) {
  $output[] = $i;
}
```